# What causes the failure to use policies and gates outside the controller in this Laravel 8 app?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app with users, roles and permissions. I use **Microsoft Azure** for user sign-in.

I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.

I get a list of *comma-separated user permissions* specific to every user role, from a `permissions` MySQL table.

I want to grant access to the *current user*, depending on the *permissions* they have.

I store the `userPermissions` variable in a session like this:

```
public function storeTokens($accessToken, $user, $user_role, $user_permissions) {
    session([
      'accessToken' => $accessToken->getToken(),
      'refreshToken' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
      'tokenExpires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
      'userName' => $user->getDisplayName(),
      'firstName' => $user->getGivenName(),
      'lastName' => $user->getSurname(),
      'userRole' => $user_role,
      'userPermissions' => $user_permissions,
      'userEmail' => null !== $user->getMail() ? $user->getMail() : $user->getUserPrincipalName(),
      'userTimeZone' => $user->getMailboxSettings()->getTimeZone()
    ]);
}
```

I have created a **UserPolicy** class

```
class UserPolicy {
    /**
     * @param  \App\Models\User $user
     * @return bool
     */

    private $user_permissions;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->user_permissions = $request->session()->get('userPermissions');
    }

    public function view_users() {
        if (!is_null($this->user_permissions)) {
          return in_array('view-users', $this->user_permissions);
        }
    }
}
```

In `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`, I define the gate(s):

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */

    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('view-users', [UserPolicy::class, 'view_users']);

        // Other gates

    }
}
```

In the controller, I can use the above:

```
public function loadViewData() {    

   // Current User Instance
    $user = new User;

    // View data
    $viewData = [];

    if ($user->can('view-users')) {
        dd('I can view users');
    }

    // Check for flash errors
    if (session('error')) {
        $viewData['error'] = session('error');
        $viewData['errorDetail'] = session('errorDetail');
    }

    // Check for logged on user
    if (session('userName')) {
        $viewData['userName'] = session('userName');
        $viewData['firstName'] = session('firstName');
        $viewData['lastName'] = session('lastName');
        $viewData['role_name'] = session('userRole');
        $viewData['userEmail'] = session('userEmail');
        $viewData['userTimeZone'] = session('userTimeZone');
    }
}
```

As a result, I can see this on the page: "I can view users".

#### The problem

The problem is that I am unable to use the policy/gate outside the controller (even though the current user *does* have the permission to view users).

Doing `Route::get('/users', [UsersContoller::class, 'index'])->can('view-users')` in `routes\web.php` results in

```
403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.
```

Also, in the view, the below code does not render the *Users* table:

```
@can('view-users') 
<h2>Users</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @if ($users)
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    @endif
</table>
@endcan
```

##### What is missing from my code?

Comment: Looks like the session is not set correctly. I try to simulate the error on a fresh application but couldn't make it work. I noticed you started your example code in the controller with `new User()`. Which doesn't seem logical to me. Could you show what code you have in the `// More code` part?

Comment: @MarkWalet More code is `$viewData = [];`

Comment: @MarkWalet The session is most likely set correctly because I can do:
`@if(session('userPermissions'))all good here@endif`

Comment: It's weird that it works in the controller then. `new User()` is not really an existing user. While the policy should work on the authenticated user. I'd expect something like `$request->user()` or `User::find($id)`.

You didn't specify the `auth` middleware on the failing route. So I think the 403 comes from the fact that there is no authenticated user. When using the `->can()` helper, the method first checks if there is a user. If not, it returns false.

This authenticated user is also passed to the policy method as the first argument. (Which you don't use right now.)

Comment: @MarkWalet I use **Microsoft Azure** for user sign-in. I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.